# Batch file (.bat): Setting a variable to a value that contains a percent (%)

Tags: batch-file

Suppose I have a batch file and I set a variable named PASSWORD in it like this:

```
set PASSWORD=Pass123%
```

If I then do:

```
echo %PASSWORD%
```

I notice that the % is ignored. The output is:

```
Pass123
```

I don't want the % to be ignored. I know that one way to do it is to add a % in front of it:

```
set PASSWORD=Pass123%%
```

Is there another way to do it? I tried using `setlocal` and quotes but it didn't work.

Comment: The percent symbol is dropped when the `SET` command executes, so your only option is to double it when you assign the variable.

Comment: BTW: Clear text passwords in script files are [anathema](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/anathema).

Comment: @Squashman I think you're right...

Answer (score 0):

### Delayed Expansion off solution

It seems that quoting the entire `set` clause works for me

```
set "password=Pass123%"
echo %password%
```

Note: this only works with delayed expansion off. To retrieve the content of `%password%` when delayed expansion is on, try this:

### Delayed Expansion on solution

```
set "password=Pass123%"
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%A in ('set password') do echo %%~A
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me... Did you try this on Windows 10?